# best way to find Minimum spanning tree cost

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have n points on coordinate plane forming a complete graph weight of an edge is abs(x1-x2)+ abs(y1-y2). I have to find the cost of minimum spanning tree I have done it using Prim's algorithm with time complexity O(n^2) is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that will require a proof but I am fairly confident about it.

First off, let's assume the 2D points can be indexed by an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) in O(n log n) and you can search for a nearest-neighbour in O(log n) in average.

Then (I am fairly certain) it can be shown that each point on the plane will in the resulting minimum spanning tree only be connected to one or more of its 60° sector-nearest neighbours. There exist only 6 of these neighbours which can be found in O(log n) for each point (by adapting the R-Tree search a little). You will thus end up with a reduced graph of 6n edges on which you can run Prim's algorithm in O(6n).

Ok, so what are the 60° sector-nearest neighbours? - If you divide the space around a point in 6 sectors each with 60° (like a pizza with 6 slices) and search for the nearest neighbour in each sector.

Proof idea: If in the resulting spanning tree a point p would be connected to another point q that is not among its 60° sector-nearest neighbours then the spanning tree could be shortened by connecting q to an adequate 60° sector-nearest neighbour of p.

Total runtime would be dominated by building and querying the R-Tree O(n log n).